# JQuery animation causing a strange flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, animation

I'm currently working on changing the header on my schools news site. I've got this little bit of JQuery code removing some of the unnecessary information from the header when you being scrolling the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("header .logo, header #search").hide(800);
            $("#float").css("padding","115px 0 15px 0");
            $("header").css("position", "fixed");
        } else {
            $("header .logo, header #search").show(0);
            $("#float").css("padding","0 0 15px 0");
            $("header").css("position", "relative");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm making the changes on our staging site [staging.theknoxstudent.com](http://staging.theknoxstudent.com).
If you take a look, you'll see the animation looks nice and smooth on the homepage, but if you go to another page on the site, it starts to look glitchy and flash. What could be causing this?

Thanks,

-Matt

Comment: It looks identical on all pages for me. Browser issue possibly?

Comment: Chrome & IE flashes, FF doesn't. I think it's how each browsers interprets the scroll events. See if the scroll event is firing twice at the start.

Comment: I saw it on Chrome last version and works fine.